# Submitting HTML form in JQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to convert an existing HTML form and make it appear in JQuery dialog. I am not sure how to change the code so the data is submitted after clicking the submit buton. My code is a follows:

Old form:

```
<form method="post" name="callbackrequest" id="ccallbackrequest" action="action.php" onsubmit="return validateThis(this)">

<button type="submit" class="submit">Submit Request</button>
```

New form:

```
buttons: {
                "Submit": function() {
if ( bValid ) {

        HERE GOES THE CODE!

        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              }
```

Then there is the new form:

```
<form class="center" method="post" name="callbackrequest" id="ccallbackrequest" action="??">
 fields listed
no submit button
</form>
```

Any advice on how should I handle this?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle and show us what is breaking?  I'm not sure what is breaking, or what behavior you want... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Nothing is braking, it is not working. I am just trying to submit the button and I don't know the code to do this in JQuery. In the HERE GOES THE CODE section there should be a call to submit the form, however i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `$('#ccallbackrequest').submit();`. The submit method just submits whichever form is returned by the selector.

Answer (score 12):

Let's take it one step further...here's a dialog form submit with ajax!

```
<form id="modalform" style="display:none">
     <input type="text" name="something">
     <input type="text" name="somethingelse">
</form>




$("#modalform").dialog({                                                            //Shows dialog
        height: 250,
        width: 450,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "Save": function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/url/to/submit",                   //
                    timeout: 30000,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $('#modalform').serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)  {
                        alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)
                    },
                    success: function(data){                                                        
                         //Do stuff here on success such as modal info      
                             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Although, I'm quite familiar with ajax, I was not sure how I was going to implement this with dialog.  This was extremely helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to put in

```
 $("#FORM_ID").submit()
```